# Full validation test in Spring Boot, injection failing

Tags: java, unit-testing, validation, spring-boot

Hello everyone I wanted to tested the full validation of a Request in my Spring Boot application I mean no testing one validator at a time but all of them on the target object)

First I have my object :

```
public class UserCreationRequest {
   @JsonProperty("profileId")
   @NotNull
   @ValidProfile
   private Integer profileId; 
}
```

Then my Validator (@ValidProfile):

```
@Component
public class ProfileValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidProfile,   Integer> {

@Autowired
private IProfileService profileService;

@Autowired
private IUserRestService userRestService;

@Override
public void initialize(ValidProfile constraintAnnotation) {

}

@Override
public boolean isValid(Integer value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    if (value == null) {
        return true;
    }

    RestUser restUser = userRestService.getRestUser();
    ProfileEntity profileEntity = profileService.getProfile(value, restUser.getAccountId());

    return profileEntity != null;
}
}
```

Now I write my unit test :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {ValidationTestConfiguration.class})
public class UserCreationRequestValidationTest {

private static LocalValidatorFactoryBean localValidatorFactory;

@Autowired
private IUserService userService;

@Autowired
private IProfileService profileService;

@Autowired
private IUserRestService restService;

@BeforeClass
public static void createValidator() {
    localValidatorFactory = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    localValidatorFactory.setProviderClass(HibernateValidator.class);
    localValidatorFactory.afterPropertiesSet();
}

@AfterClass
public static void close() {
    localValidatorFactory.close();
}    

@Test
public void validateUserCreationRequestStringfields() {

    UserCreationRequest userCreationRequest = new UserCreationRequest();
    /* Here fill test object*/

    when(userService.getUser(any(Integer.class), any(Integer.class))).thenReturn(new UserEntity());
    when(profileService.getProfile(any(Integer.class), any(Integer.class))).thenReturn(new ProfileEntity());
    when(restService.getRestUser()).thenReturn(new RestUser());

    Set<ConstraintViolation<UserCreationRequest>> violations
            = localValidatorFactory.validate(userCreationRequest);

    assertEquals(violations.size(), 8);
}
}
```

and my TestConfiguration is like that :

```
@Configuration
public class ValidationTestConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public IProfileService profileService() {
        return Mockito.mock(IProfileService.class);
    }   

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public IUserRestService userRestService() { return Mockito.mock(IUserRestService.class); }
}
```

On execution I can see that in the test itself the injection works :
restService is mapped to "Mock for IUserRestService"

But in my validator it is not injected, userRestService is null.

Same thing for ProfileService

I tried several things seen here, nothing works (code is running, only test conf is failing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you do not produce the Validator bean so it can be injected.

As you manually instantiate the LocalValidatorFactoryBean, it cannot access to the spring DI defined for this test.

You should produce instead a bean for the Validator,  or even reference an existing spring configuration to do so.